# How to vectorize this pandas operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping, vectorization

I have a dataset of shape 4200,8. First row looks like this:

```
X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8
32  23  17  0   3   24  9   14
```

Each value is a categorical encoding that corresponds to a list of 30 values, that looks like this:

```
[ 0.06405287, -0.1176078 , -0.06206927,  0.08389127, -0.18036067,
  0.35158703, -0.0928449 , -0.0974429 , -0.06705306, -0.17196381,
 -0.03776502,  0.09204011,  0.47813812,  0.16258538,  0.2699648 ,
  0.07496626, -0.09791522, -0.31499937, -0.24898018,  0.06126055,
  0.13187763,  0.21042736, -0.1585868 ,  0.08355565, -0.13935572,
  0.12408883,  0.2043313 , -0.12544186, -0.09223691,  0.00720569 ]
```

My goal is to create a column for each value in this list, at the position of the list's corresponding categorical encoding. The list above corresponds to the value `14` at column `X8`, so instead of: `X8 : 14` I have:

```
X8_1 X8_2 X8_3 ... X8_29 X8_30
0.06 -0.11 -0.62 ...-0.09 0.007
```

The end result being my dataframe of 8 columns becomes a dataframe of 240 columns. Of course, each row has a different set of values. Here's how I've done this:
I get each unique value in the column, create a dictionary of
`colname:uniqueval:indexoflist:listvalatindex`. Then I create a dictionary out of each row of the dataframe, and for each column and value in column I get the corresponding list and concatenate. Then I concatenate that row to the previous row.

```
weights = {}
for index, x in enumerate(encoded.columns): #this is the dataset with the original encoded values
  weights[x] = {}
  for id, val in enumerate(encoded[x].unique()):
    weights[x][val] = {}
    for weightid, weightval in enumerate(model_full.get_layer(embeddings[index]).get_weights()[0][id]): #this is where I get the list of 30 values from
      weights[x][val][weightid] = weightval

mappedembeddings = pd.DataFrame()
encodedindex = []
for row in encoded.iterrows(): #iterate over original dataset
  encodedindex.append(row[0]) #store index for later
  df0 = pd.DataFrame()
  for k, v in row[1].to_dict().items(): #for each key/val in row
    names = []
    for z in weights[k][v].keys():
      names.append(str(k)+'_'+str(z)) #naming (z is key of list value)

    tempdf = pd.DataFrame([weights[k][v]]) #dataframe of list at column/value key in dictionary made from embedding layer list
    tempdf.columns = names
    df0 = pd.concat([df0,tempdf],axis=1) 

  mappedembeddings = pd.concat([mappedembeddings,df0],axis=0) #concat row to previous row
  
mappedembeddings.index = encodedindex
```

This takes a long time. I would like to vectorize this operation, but I'm unsure how to proceed, so I'd appreciate some insights.

Comment: What are the list of 30 values saved as? For example if I want to get the list for value 14? Also are the mapping for the values to the list same for all rows of your DataFrame?

Comment: @not_speshal Hello! `weights['X8'][14]` would get the list for value 14. They are saved as a nested dictionary, which is built from this structure: `model_full.get_layer(embeddings["""column_name"""]).get_weights()[0]["""unique_value"""]`. About the mapping- the same values correspond to the same list. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `map` each of your column values to the respective lists
2. `explode` the lists to individual rows and `stack`
3. create the required columns names with `groupby`
4. `pivot` to get the output

```
values = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(weights[x.name]))
values = values.explode(list(values.columns)).stack().reset_index()
values["column"] = values["level_1"] + "_" + (values.groupby(["level_0", "level_1"]).transform("cumcount")+1).astype(str)
output = values.pivot("level_0", "column", 0)
```

###### Full working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

#random dataframe with three columns X0 X1 and X2
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(30, size=(2,3)),
                  columns = [f"X{i}" for i in range(3)]
                  )

#creating weights dictionary 
#weights[col][number]: list of 5 numbers
weights = dict()
for c in df.columns:
    weights[c] = {num: np.random.rand(5) for num in df[c].unique()}
    
values = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(weights[x.name]))
values = values.explode(list(values.columns)).stack().reset_index()
values["column"] = values["level_1"] + "_" + (values.groupby(["level_0", "level_1"]).transform("cumcount")+1).astype(str)
output = values.pivot("level_0", "column", 0)

>>> output
column       X0_1      X0_2      X0_3  ...      X2_3      X2_4      X2_5
level_0                                ...                              
0        0.844776  0.004719  0.121569  ...  0.372832  0.005689  0.252426
1        0.136707  0.575093  0.891322  ...  0.598843  0.603805  0.105148

[2 rows x 15 columns]
```